# jQuery: move the complete element into another one, but not its content only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There is the source DIV element that must appear within the target DIV.

And there is jQuery `appendTo` method that seems to do that for me.

For example:

```
<div class="source">Move Me</div>
<div class="destination"></div>

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.source').contents().appendTo('.destination')
  });
```

But actually it only moves source's content into the target DIV, keeping the empty source DIV where it originally was: here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mn0cvdhh/) that demonstrates this.

So, instead of

```
<div class="destination">
    <div class="source">Move Me</div>
</div>
```

the `appendTo` result is just

```
<div class="source"></div>
<div class="destination">Move Me</div>
```

Is there a way to achieve

```
<div class="destination">
    <div class="source">Move Me</div>
</div>
```

without extra wrapping elements?

Comment: `jQuery('.source').appendTo('.destination')`

Comment: You're calling `.contents()`, so that only moves...wait for it...the contents.

Comment: I've taken the script I'm using at the other fragment of the page and neither while filling JSFiddle nor while creating this question I haven't noticed the `.contents()` in my text! That's probably because it is 5:30am. Anyway it's hard to be a beginner... @MichaelCoker, you were the first, please repost your reply as the answer so that I could upvote it. Thanks a lot to both of you :)

Comment: @YKKY you're welcome, will do. Thanks for being fair about that!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$.contents()` will grab the content of the element, but leave the element itself alone. The default behavior of `$.append()` and `$.appendTo()` is to move the entire element. So in your example, you simply need to use `jQuery('.source').appendTo('.destination')` and that will move `.source` in to `.destination`

```js
jQuery('.source').appendTo('.destination')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="source">Move Me</div>
<div class="destination"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just get rid of that .contents() method to move the whole element.

```
$('.destination').append($('.source'))
```

will turn

```
<div class="destination"></div>
<div class="source">Move Me</div>
```

into

```
<div class="destination">
     <div class="source">Move Me</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply exclude `.contents()` in your own solution, this way:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.source').appendTo('.destination')
});
```

Then it will move `Div.source` completely into `Div.destination`. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/NDFA/cur9qg2w/

Answer (score 0):

First all.The Jquery's `appendTo` behavior is append after an element to another element. So that behavior is correct. Also `append` method may be you need.